# Can you make KNPMenu Voters Private?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, knpmenubundle

I'm trying generate breadcrumbs as per the recent (2.2) update but am having a problem getting the correct current item 
via:

```
knp_menu_get_current_item()
```

After a bunch of digging I found a conflict with a Voter that's been included from SonataAdmin

```
Sonata\AdminBundle\Menu\Matcher\Voter\ChildrenVote
```

This is returning true for each ancestor element in the tree so the root node is being returned as `current` and as such the breadcrumb isn't being generated properly. Removing the `ChildrenVote` voter makes my breadcrumbs spiffing.

Is there a way to restrict the Voters to specific Menus or can I explicitly define which Voters to use for a given Menu?

Installed versions:

```
sonata/admin-bundle: 3.10.2
knplabs/knp-menu: 2.2.0
```